# Is $C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ a subset of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I came across this while reading something but I cannot seem to prove it. Any ideas?

> Prove that $C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$

This is what I tried:

Let $f \in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists M > 0$ such that $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ for $x \notin [-M,M]$. However, this does not help as the measure of $(-\infty,M) \cup (M,\infty)$ is infinite. Also, I do not understand how differentiability helps.

---

**EDIT:** The notation did me in. The author did mean smooth functions with compact support. The usual space of smooth functions vanishing at infinity is not a subset of $L^{2}$ as the example $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for $x > 0$ shows.

Comment: For that to be true, I suppose the author defined $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ as the space of $C^\infty$ functions with compact support?

Comment: If $f$ is compactly supported, it is rather trivial. Perhaps author did intend to mean compact support rather than the usual meaning of vanishing at infinity. I will check it.

Comment: You are using $C_0^\infty$ to denote the space of functions vanishing at infinity (as it should be). But that space is __not__ contained in $L^2$. I think the author denotes by $C_0^\infty$ what ought to be denoted by $C_c^\infty$, or by $\mathscr{D}$.

Comment: Since it was just a notation-mixup (as expected), I don't think the question is likely to help future visitors. You may consider deleting it. Or posting a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\beta(x) = 1_{(-1,1)}(x) e^{- \frac{1}{1-x^2} }$ is smooth and has support on (-1,1). Hence $\psi(x) = \frac{1}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \beta(t) dt}\int_{-\infty}^x \beta(t) dt $ is smooth, $\psi(x)=0$ for $x \in (-\infty,1]$,$\psi(x) \in [0,1]$ for  $x \in [0,1]$, and $\psi(x) = 1$ for $x \in [1,\infty)$.

Let $f(x) = \psi(x-2) \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. Then $f \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, but $f \notin L^2(\mathbb{R})$.